Explanation of ayah 82 of Sura Al-Ma'ida (5 th sura)

You will surely find the most intense of the people in animosity toward the believers [to be] the Jews and those who associate others with Allah; and you will find the nearest of them in affection to the believers those who say, "We are Christians." That is because among them are priests and monks and because they are not arrogant.

According to this ayah, Jews and idol worshippers (e.g., Hindus) will be the staunchest enemies of Muslims. On the other hand, practicing Christians (of any denomination) will be in favor of Muslims.
If we consider the current world politics and domestic politics of various countries, this seems to be 50% true and 50% untrue.
For example, according to the Pew Research 2019 survey, Eastern European Catholic countries are overwhelmingly anti-Muslim.
Also, American evangelical Christians are overwhelmingly anti-Muslim.
So, how is this ayah justified?


How are you sure this verse referring to today's political situation. It could very well be referring to jews of madina and Christian and later became muslim like king Najashi from during the time of prophet peace and blessing be upon him.
I will give you an example:
In chapter 9, Allah tells us how Jews have taken erza as son of God. This verse doesn't apply to all jews rather group of jew that was present in Medina at the time, as scholars have said. So the Quran here is not telling us universal belief of the jews rather addressing the contemporary audience of 7th century and us in the future as part of the history.
So this verse you referring to can very very well be addressing the contemporary audience of 7th century and informing us of the history.
Even if it's referring to today's political situation, why are you referring to pew research. Just look at how many Christians support ours brother and sisters in Palestine vs Hindus supporting the Isrealie terrorists.
Hope this answers the question.
